# Restricting access via meteor mongo

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm asking this out of concern for my database's security. Meteor encourages developers to remove the `insecure` package and move all database-altering operations to methods executed safely on the server, which one can happily do.

However, it strikes me after deploying to mywebsite.com with `meteor deploy mywebsite.com` that the command `meteor mongo mywebsite.com` seems to be accessible and connective for anyone who cares to run it? How would one mitigate this direct access, or is it not actually as open as I believe?

Answer (score 0):

I was worried for no reason - the credentials that you set up when deploying an application for the first time are required for access to the production database from an unfamiliar machine. You will be interactively prompted when accessing via `meteor mongo`.